# Accurate weapon grip animation in UE5

Tags: game-physics, game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I want to achieve an accurate animation of grabbing a weapon, like for example in rdr or tlou in these games, regardless of the character’s actions, whether he is walking or sneaking, the character will always perfectly pull the gun out of the holster. Is it possible to somehow make a procedural animation so that, regardless of the position, the character always clearly reaches for the handle? I also use ALS V4

I use the socket system, but I think this is not the right approach.